# ОШИБКА sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (sqlite3.IntegrityError) NOT NULL constraint failed: users.id

Tags: sqlalchemy

в инете много вопросов про это но ответов либо нет, либо не помогают

ошибка: sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (sqlite3.IntegrityError) NOT NULL constraint failed: users.id

код:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for,request, redirect
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from datetime import datetime

app=Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///blog.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
app.app_context().push()

class Users(db.Model):
    id=db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    vozrast=db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    name=db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False)
    familia=db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False)
    pol=db.Column(db.Text(20), nullable=False)
    date_reg=db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Users %r>' % self.id

@app.route('/')
def mainl():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route('/info')
def infl():
    return render_template("info.html")

@app.route('/account/<string:login>/<string:password>', methods=['POST','GET'])
def acc(login,password):
    if login == "admin" and password == "admin":
        if request.method=="POST":
            vozrast =request.form['vozrast']
            name =request.form['name']
            familia =request.form['familia']
            pol =request.form['pol']

            users = Users(vozrast=vozrast,name=name,familia=familia,pol=pol)


            db.session.add(users)
            db.session.commit()
            return redirect('/')

        else:
            return render_template("account.html")
    else:
        return redirect('/')

if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы забыли создать базу:

```
if __name__=="__main__":
    with app.app_context():
        db.create_all()
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: в конце моего кода есть 

if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)

поменял это на то что вы написали, не помогло

Comment: ошибка не изменилась?

Comment: нет:

sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (sqlite3.IntegrityError) NOT NULL constraint failed: users.id 
[SQL: INSERT INTO users (vozrast, name, familia, pol, date_reg) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)] 
[parameters: ('77', 'имя', 'фамилия', 'пол', '2023-12-18 13:45:00.829387')] 
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/gkpj)

Comment: Пропробуйте удалить автоинкремент. `id=db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)`